# Wagtail: Filter Page model by a field on the child

Tags: django, parent-child, wagtail, django-treebeard

I have two models, `ParentPage` and `ChildPage`. I want to find the set of `ParentPage`s where a field `is_completed` is `True` on the `ChildPage`.

Normally in Django, I could do something like

`ParentPage.objects.filter(child_page__is_completed=True)`

However, I don't think there is a join here for the Wagtail/Treebeard hierarchy.

I also thought you might be able to filter `ChildPage`s by multiple `ParentPage`s, e.g. `ChildPage.objects.children_of([parent_ids])`, but I can't see a way to do that either.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Page table has `path` and `url_path` columns. If you find all children and strip the last part of the `path` or `url_path`, you can use that result to query the parent pages.

Path:

```
child_paths = ChildPage.objects.filter(is_completed=True).values_list("path", flat=True)
parent_paths = set([cp[:-4] for cp in child_paths])
pages = Page.objects.filter(path__in=parent_paths)
```

Url path:

```
child_urls = ChildPage.objects.filter(is_completed=True).values_list("url_path", flat=True)
parent_urls = set([url.rsplit('/', 1)[0] for url in child_urls])
pages = Page.objects.filter(url_path__in=parent_urls)
```

Disclaimer: untested code.

Comment: The other idea I had was just to set a foreign key on save. Might still be worth doing depending on how performant this is in comparison.